# What holds the unknowns and coefficients in $R[x][y]$ together?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring $R[x][y]$. I am not sure that I know exactly what is going on here. A typical element of the ring is a polynomial in $y$ with coefficients that are themselves polynomials in $x$.

For example: $p=(x^2+ax+b)y^3+(x+c)y$ where $a,b,c \in R$.

So, the polynomial above is an element of $R[x][y]$, but am I allowed to distribute the $y^3$ and $y$ over each of the coefficients? Or is this not allowed by the ring $R[x][y]$?

Now, $(x^2+ax+b) \in R[x][y]$ and $y^3 \in R[x][y]$
and so $(x^2+ax+b) \cdot y^3=x^2y^3+axy^3+by^3 \in R[x][y]$ by distributivity in $R[x][y]$.

But the then does $x^2y^3+axy^3+by^3=(x^2+ax+b)y^3$?

In other words, is multiplication in $R[x][y]$ the operation that holds the coefficients in $R[x]$ and the unknowns in $y$ together? Or are the polynomials in $R[x][y]$ merely syntactical and can't be manipulated as above?

Comment: Note that $R[x][y] = R[x, y]$.

Comment: @JonasHardt are they equal or isomorphic? because the post below claims isomorphic

Comment: You can do this even if the coefficients *aren't* polynomials. For example, you can write $x^2+x+1$ as $2x^2-x^2+3x-x-x-1+2$ if you want.

Comment: They are canonically isomorphic which is pretty equal.

Comment: Some people define $R[x, y]$ to mean $R[x][y]$, while others don't.

Comment: Such (re)distribution equalities hold in any commutive ring (or more generally for $x,y\in S\supset R$ such that  $x$, $y$ and all $\,r\in R$ all commute with each other - which is necessary (& sufficient) to rewrite to form $\,\sum r_i x^{i_1} y^{i_2}$)

Comment: I am not sure to understand your doubts. You write $$"(x^2+ax+b) \cdot y^3=x^2y^3+axy^3+by^3 $$ by distributivity " and then ask $$"x^2y^3+axy^3+by^3=(x^2+ax+b)y^3?".$$ You seem to believe there are two multiplications in $R[x][y].$

Comment: This is what I am trying to ask: Let $*$ be the multiplication operation in $R[x]$. Write an element out in $R[x]$: $r_nx^n+r_{n-1}x^{n-1}...+r_0$. By this, do we actually mean:  $r_n*x^n+r_{n-1}*x^{n-1}...+r_0$? Or is it the case that each monomial in the sum is merely syntactical: that is, there is no operation holding $x^i$ and a coefficient in $R$ together?

Comment: @AnneBauval is this last question more clear?

Comment: Not really. Now you are talking of $R[x],$ not of  $R[x][y].$ But there is as well only one multiplication in that ring. You can use the $*$ sign to denote it, or as usual no sign at all. So: you can write $r*x*x,$ or as usual $rx^2.$

Comment: I don't think anyone should _define_ $R[x][y]$ to mean $R[x,y]$, as $S[X]$ should have a meaning for any commutative ring $S$ and and any set $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a theorem that for any commutative ring $R$ there is an isomorphism $R[x][y]\cong R[x,y]\cong R[y][x]$ given by switching your perspective (polynomial in $y$ with coefficients polynomials $x$ is the same thing as a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients polynomials in $y$). This is a good supplementary point to your question, as not only is it valid to distribute and rearrange everything (which is permissible just by ring axioms) but you can formalise the idea that these rearrangements can turn any polynomial in $y$ into one in $x$, that there is essentially no difference.

---

The ring structure of $R[x][y]$ *does* permit something like $(x^2+1)y^2+y=x^2y^2+(y^2+y)$. All you have done there is use associativity and the distributivity of multiplication. $1\in R[x],x^2\in R[x]$, … there is no problem making that equality an equality in $R[x][y]$.

All of your equalities are valid equalities in $R[x][y]$. In asking: “is $x^2y^3+axy^3=(x^2+ax)y^3$ in $R[x][y]$” (where $a\in R$) you are asking: “is $cy^3+dy^3=(c+d)y^3$ in $K[y]$ where $c,d\in K$” (where $K=R[x]$ and $c=x^2,d=ax$) and yes, that is true by definition of $K[y]$.

Comment: The distributive property is in fact a ring axiom.

Comment: The more precise version of what I meant is the ring isomorphisms, which are a theorem. @runway44 But I’ll edit to make what I meant clearer (distribute + rearrange + shift your perspective)

Comment: @FShrike so when I write $p(x)y^n+... \in R[x][y]$ the "thing" holding $p(x)$ and $y^n$ together is the multiplication operation in $R[x][y]$ correct?

Comment: @violet I guess..? I’m not sure what precisely you’re getting at by the “thing holding it together” but the ring structure of $R[x][y]$ is just that of $K[y]$ where $K$ is the ring $R[x]$. $p(x)y^n+q(x)y^m$ is just $ky^n+k’y^m$ for some coefficients $k,k’\in K$ and it makes sense in $K[y]$ by very definition of $K[y]$

Answer (score 1):

Every [polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) $S[y]$, over some commutative ring $S$, is itself a (commutative) ring and as such, satisfies the distributivity property
$$(P(y)+Q(y))T(y)=P(y)T(y)+
Q(y)T(y),$$
e.g.
$$(s_1+s_2)y^3=s_1y^3+s_2y^3$$
for $s_i\in S,$ and same for sums of three terms.

Apply this to $S=R[x]$ and $$(s_1,s_2,s_3)=(x^2,ax,b).$$